# How can we do Data Replication on SQL Server 2012 . For detail please read below

Tags: replication, sql-server-2012

> I have a database Now what I want If in any case my database server
>   has failed then it automatically gets data from another server. I want
>   to know how can we do Data Replication/Mirroring.
>
> Can anybody share an idea how we can do this?
>
> I have searched a lot in the Google but doesn't get exact link for the
>   Data Replication on SQL Server 2012. I really appreciate your
>   suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For failover type scenarios, you want to use either Mirroring or Always on, not replication.

Details on Mirroring are available here:

[Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx)

Details on Always On are available here:

[SQL 2012 Always On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff877884.aspx)

Both of these solutions are able to provide automatic failover for applications to a separate copy of the database if the primary server fails, AlwaysOn is the better solution (and mirroring is now apparently deprecated as of SQL 2012) but has some more complex requirements such as a dependency on windows clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for SQL Server Replication can be found in [Books Online for SQL Server 2012 - SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx).